# Query Camel case json documents in Azure CosmosDB

Tags: json, camelcasing, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have created collections with camelcase partition keys like `\locationId` instead of `\LocationId`. Also when inserting / updating documents in cosmosdb, i have added them as camelcase using below code :

```
T entity = null;
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings 
{ 
      ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() 
};

var messageBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entity, Formatting.Indented, settings);

using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageBody)))
{
      var res = Resource.LoadFrom<Document>(memoryStream);
      await _client.UpsertDocumentAsync((await _collection).SelfLink, res, option);
}
```

However, when retriving any document using linq condition, the result is always null. I have decorated all CosmosDB T types with `[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]`

Am i missing something here?